# PHP to Java Forum - Game Integration

Tags: java, php, mysql

so I am creating a game and am trying to integrate forum registration with logging into the actual game. Here is my PHP code.

```
 <?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$name = "database";
$_GET['name'] = str_replace("_"," ",$_GET['name']);
if($_GET['crypt'] != 168284692){
    echo '-1';
    exit;
}
if(!@mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass))  {
    die("error connecting to mysql server - " . mysql_error()); 
}
if(!@mysql_select_db($name))  {
    die("error selecting mysql database - " . mysql_error());
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_members WHERE members_display_name = '".$_GET['name']."'");
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$pass2 = md5(md5($row["members_pass_salt"]).md5($_GET['pass']));
if($_GET['pass'] == $row["members_pass_hash"])
    echo ''.(2+$row["member_group_id"]);
else
    echo '1';
} else
echo '0';
?>
```

The issue however is not with connecting to the database, that works just fine. The issue is that when I call from the page in my source code, it returns  and runs the catch exception

```
try {
            //the url for your website
            String urlString = "http://website.com/CheckUserOnLogin.php?crypt="+CRYPTION_ID+"&name="+user+"&pass="+pass;
            //open the connection to your website, this will throw and error if offline
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            //read the result of the login
            String line = in.readLine().trim();
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
            try {
                //parse the return code from the responce
                int returnCode = Integer.parseInt(line);
                switch(returnCode){
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("Wrong CRYPTION_ID");
                    return 10;
                case 1://invalid password
                    return 3;
                case 0://no member exists for this username
                    return 12;//say they must register on forum
                    //return 2;//allow login
                default://login ok
                    int member_group_id = returnCode-2;
                    return 2;
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("here");
                //only called if failed to connect to the database
                System.out.println(line);
                return 8;//login server down
            }
        } catch(Exception e2){
            //should only happen if failed to connect to website
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 11;//website offline
    }
```

I'm using an IPB Forum, i'm unsure as to why its returning this `</br>`

Thanks - Grant